# Creating a notification when app is not running

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

On this app I'm working on, I would like to get notifications when the app is not in the foreground. Basically when you're in the app your online and users can send you messages. Depending on where you are in the app you'll get a dialog stating you received a message or get the full text in the message activity. However I want to deal with messages you received when you're not running the app. I already built a notification activity but I don't know how to keep an app running in the background and to push up notifications.

Here is an example of an activity that would received an alert that a message was sent to you

```
public class TabExercise extends TabActivity implements ChatCallbackAdapter{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public StartSocket connect;
    public static Context mContext;
    private ConnectSocket connectsocket;
    final Context context = this;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_exercise);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        connectsocket= new ConnectSocket(this);
        connectsocket.start();
       // connect=new StartSocket();
        mContext=TabExercise.this;
        // Tab for Contacts
        TabSpec contacts = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contacts");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        contacts.setIndicator("Contacts", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        Intent contactsIntent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
        contacts.setContent(contactsIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Notifications");        
        songspec.setIndicator("Notifications", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Notifications.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Messages");
        videospec.setIndicator("Messages", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, MyMessages.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(contacts); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab

        TabWidget widget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
        for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = widget.getChildAt(i);

            // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            if(tv == null) {
                continue;

            }
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.tab_indicator_holo);
        }
        Intent in= getIntent();
        String tabSel=in.getStringExtra("tab_index");
        //Bundle extras = in.getExtras();
        if (tabSel != null) {

            if(tabSel.equals("1")){
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(Integer.valueOf(tabSel)); 
            }
            if(tabSel.equals("2")){
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(Integer.valueOf(tabSel)); 
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    //  SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
     //   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView(); 
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
     //   searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        //searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
     //   searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                SaveSharedPreference.setUserName(TabExercise.this,"");
                SaveSharedPreference.setName(TabExercise.this,"");
                SaveSharedPreference.setUserId(TabExercise.this,"");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.find_a_user:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home

                Intent in = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);

                startActivity(in);
                return true;

            case R.id.editprofile:

                Intent inte=new Intent(this, EditProfile.class);
                startActivity(inte);
                return true;
            case R.id.chat:
                Intent inti = new Intent(this, StartChat.class);
                startActivity(inti);
                return true;

            case R.id.delete_all:
                //connect.start();
                Intent inten=new Intent(TabExercise.this, CreateNotification.class);
                startActivity(inten);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void callback(JSONArray data) throws JSONException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void on(String event, JSONObject data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectFailure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(Message m) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Status","This is the status "+m.status);
        if(m.status.equals("ready")){
            connectsocket.login(SaveSharedPreference.getName(TabExercise.this), SaveSharedPreference.getUserId(TabExercise.this));
            connectsocket.subscribe();
        }
        if(m.status.equals("call")){
            Intent intent=new Intent(TabExercise.this, StartCall.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(m.status.equals("message")){
            System.out.println("Received a message "+m.msg+" and a name "+m.name);
            final String name=m.name;
            final String pid=m.pid;
            final String msg=m.msg;

            //Intent intenter=new Intent(TabExercise.this, CreateNotification.class);
            //startActivity(intenter);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
             AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
             alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(name+" just sent you a message");
             alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click yes to go to the message");
             alertDialogBuilder

                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        Intent inte=new Intent(TabExercise.this, Chat.class);
                        Bundle extras=new Bundle();
                        extras.putString("name", name);
                        extras.putString("pid", pid);
                        extras.putString("msg", msg);
                        inte.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivity(inte);

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            });
        }
    }
```

and here is the notification activity that creates notifications.

```
public class CreateNotification extends Activity {
    View viewer;
     @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_notification);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiveNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Received a message")
            .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Rply", pIntent)
            .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alarm manager to periodically trigger alarm. When an alarm is received, run a background service to poll your server for any messages received.

Or else if you want your server to push messages directly to your device, you can use Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: ahhh Interesting, let me look into that.